# I can’t start the server - jekyll

Tags: node.js, gulp, jekyll

Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. If you've run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, ensure that you have included the jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin gem in your Gemfile as well. The full error message from Ruby is: 'Unable to activate jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin-1.6.0, because jekyll-4.0.0 conflicts with jekyll (< 4.0, >= 2.0)' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!

**what to do with it?
if i use:**

$ jekyll build --trace
Configuration file: /home/user/s/villaanna/_config.yml
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. If you've run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, ensure that you have included the jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin gem in your Gemfile as well. The full error message from Ruby is: 'Unable to activate jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin-1.6.0, because jekyll-4.0.0 conflicts with jekyll (< 4.0, >= 2.0)' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/! 
Traceback (most recent call last):
        21: from /home/user/gems/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
        20: from /home/user/gems/bin/jekyll:23:in`load'
        19: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        18: from /home/user/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in`program'
        17: from /home/user/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        16: from /home/user/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in`execute'
        15: from /home/user/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        14: from /home/user/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in`block in execute'
        13: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        12: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in`process_with_graceful_fail'
        11: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `each'
        10: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in`block in process_with_graceful_fail'
         9: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
         8: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in`new'
         7: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:34:in `initialize'
         6: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:124:in`setup'
         5: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:22:in `conscientious_require'
         4: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:30:in`require_gems'
         3: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:57:in `require_with_graceful_fail'
         2: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:57:in`each'
         1: from /home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:58:in `block in require_with_graceful_fail'
/home/user/gems/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:73:in`rescue in block in require_with_graceful_fail': jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin (Jekyll::Errors::MissingDependencyException)

**the fact is that I installed "jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin"
I can not understand what the problem is
my gem list:**

$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

addressable (2.7.0)
bigdecimal (default: 1.3.4)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (2.0.2)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
colorator (1.1.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
csv (default: 1.0.0)
date (default: 1.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.0.0)
did_you_mean (1.2.0)
em-websocket (0.5.1)
etc (default: 1.0.0)
eventmachine (1.2.7)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
ffi (1.11.1)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.0.2)
forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
gdbm (default: 2.0.0)
http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
i18n (1.7.0, 0.9.5)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.0)
jekyll (4.0.0, 3.8.6)
jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin (1.6.0)
jekyll-sass-converter (2.0.1, 1.5.2)
jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
json (default: 2.1.0)
kramdown (2.1.0, 1.17.0)
kramdown-parser-gfm (1.1.0)
liquid (4.0.3)
listen (3.2.0)
mercenary (0.3.6)
minitest (5.10.3)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
openssl (default: 2.1.1)
pathutil (0.16.2)
power_assert (0.2.7)
psych (default: 3.0.2)
public_suffix (4.0.1)
rake (12.3.1)
rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
rb-inotify (0.10.0)
rdoc (default: 6.0.1)
rouge (3.12.0)
safe_yaml (1.0.5)
sass (3.7.4)
sass-listen (4.0.0)
sassc (2.2.1)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
stringio (default: 0.0.1)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
terminal-table (1.8.0)
test-unit (3.2.5)
unicode-display_width (1.6.0)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the jekyll-mulitple-languages-plugin gem, as stated in the error and add the gem to your Gemfile. Once you have done that you need to run Jekyll with 'bundle exec jekyll serve'. Which part of that process is confusing to you?

Ah... I see... the error further states:

> Unable to activate jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin-1.6.0, because jekyll-4.0.0 conflicts with jekyll (< 4.0, >= 2.0)

... which means you installed Jekyll 4.0 but the plugin requires a Jekyll version lower than 4.0 and higher than 2.0.

Comment: the fact is that I installed "jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin"
I can not understand what the problem is